# Chron Help, System.StringException and Day-of-month parameter not implemented

Tags: apex

Hello I know there are resources all over but I can't get my issue worked. I followed [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm) chart but I am still getting various errors. I hope it's just a problem with my chron and not some the rest of the code.

```
Vantage_Connector_Test test = new Vantage_Connector_Test();

String sch = '0 2 9 * * 1-5';

String jobID = System.schedule('Vantage Test', sch, test);
```

... I want to schedule every weekday at 9.02 am. When I use this one I get:

> System.StringException: Support for specifying both a day-of-week AND a day-of-month parameter is not implemented.

So I take out what i think is the day-of-month parameter:

```
'0 2 9 * 1-5'
```

but then I get:

> System.StringException: Unexpected end of expression.

Are chron expressions the same everywhere? I read error wrong the first time; I thought it said ..'day-of-month parameter not supported' but it's actually 'day-of-month parameter not IMPLEMENTED'. What does that mean ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `?` instead of `*`, which means "don't care." Also, Sunday is day 1, so you probably meant to use 2-6, instead.

```
0 2 9 ? * 2-6
```

Answer (score 5):

[Using this tool](http://www.cronmaker.com/) I came up with the expression

`0 2 9 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *`

And according to [this site](http://www.baeldung.com/cron-expressions):

> Over time, the cron expression format became widely adopted and can often be used in many other programs and libraries.

It doesn't explicitly say it's universal, but it is widely adopted

Answer (score 3):

Not implemented means the same thing as not supported. (for all intent and purposes)

[Supported Cron Expressions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) (**See Using the System.Schedule Method**)

> ? Specifies no specific value. This is only available for Day_of_month
>   and Day_of_week, and is generally used when specifying a value for one
>   and not the other.

In you're first expression it's treating the `1-5` as the day of week and your first `*` parameter as day of month which is why you got that first error.

In your second one it is treating your `*` as day-of-month parameter and your `1-5` as month parameter. You're getting the error because it's expecting more parameters.

What you want is something like this: `'0 2 9 ? * 2-6'` or `'0 2 9 ? * MON-FRI'`